# EventFilter consume() does not prevent SpaceChars in TextField

Tags: javafx-8

I have a JavaFX GUI where I wish to intercept the pressing of the SpaceBar and use it to call a method. I wrote an EventFilter that seems to do the trick. It includes the command *event.consume()* which I believe is supposed to keep the *KeyEvent* from propagating to the various controls.

My issue is that when I added a *TextField*, and this field has the focus, the Spacebar presses are not being consumed as I thought they would. The " " are captured by the TextField. I would like to intercept and prevent the " " from being added to the TextField.

What am I leaving out in the code below in order to keep " " from reaching the TextField? The api, if I am reading it correctly, says that filters registered with a parent control can intercept an event before it reaches the children nodes. But even when putting the filter directly on the TextField, I am still having " " chars appear in the TextField.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;

import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;

import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class SpaceIntercept extends Application implements EventHandler <KeyEvent>
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {   
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) 
    {
        TextField textField = new TextField("asdf");
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 100);
        scene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.ANY, event -> handle(event));        
        // root.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.ANY, event -> handle(event));
        // textField.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.ANY, event -> handle(event)); 
        root.getChildren().add(textField); 
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent event) 
    {
        if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE)
        {
            if (event.getEventType() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED)
            {
                System.out.println("Code that responds to SpaceBar");
            }
            event.consume();
        }
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text field is probably listening for `KEY_TYPED` events. As is [well-documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html), `getCode()` returns `KeyCode.UNDEFINED` for a `KEY_TYPED` event. Thus you do not catch this case.

You can check for the `character` variable as well as the `code` variable to handle all cases:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;

import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;

import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class SpaceIntercept extends Application implements EventHandler <KeyEvent>
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {   
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) 
    {
        TextField textField = new TextField("asdf");
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 100);
        scene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.ANY, event -> handle(event));        
        // root.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.ANY, event -> handle(event));
        // textField.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.ANY, event -> handle(event)); 
        root.getChildren().add(textField); 
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent event) 
    {
        if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE  || " ".equals(event.getCharacter()))
        {
            if (event.getEventType() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED)
            {
                System.out.println("Code that responds to SpaceBar");
            }
            event.consume();
        }
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution i can think,which although doesn't blocks the space from being added to the `TextField`,but it replaces it after it has been added almost instantly is adding a `changeListener` to the `TextProperty` of the `TextField`:

```
textField.textProperty().addListener((observable,oldValue,newValue)->{  
    textField.setText(textField.getText().replace(" ", ""));
});
```

This may also be helpfull http://fxexperience.com/2012/02/restricting-input-on-a-textfield/

Comment: @James_D Almost didn't saw it.Thanks,anyway i edited the answer and it works even if the `SPACE` is between the existing text.Although it's just a guess if the OP needs this.

Comment: I found this answer useful. My first attempts at replacing the TextField contents did not work, so it is good to see how you did it. James_D's answer was selected because it eliminates the need to edit the field.

Comment: @Phil Freihofner And that's how it should.I also didn't knew the solution that James_D added in his answer ;)